# TypeError with an instance method

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-class

I'm trying to creat an instance method that gives me the position of an istance by its score ('count'):

```
def ordinal_inator(num):
    last = int(str(num)[-1])
    if 4 <= num <= 20:
        suffix = 'th'
    elif last == 1:
        suffix = 'st'
    elif last == 2:
        suffix = 'nd'
    elif last == 3:
        suffix = 'rd'
    else:
        suffix = 'th'

    return num + suffix


class Cal:
    count = 0
    member_list = list()

    def __init__(self, name):
        if name not in Cal.member_list:
            Cal.member_list.append(name)
        self.count += 1

    def positione(self):
        members = dict()
        for member in Cal.member_list:
            members[member] = member.count
        sorted_members = sorted(members.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
        cardinal_position = sorted_members.index(self)
        ordinal_position = ordinal_inator(cardinal_position)
        return ordinal_position


for i in range(3):
    gino = Cal('gino')
for j in range(2):
    nono = Cal('nono')
nina = Cal('nina')

print(gino.positione())
```

If I run it, python gives me an error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'

on line 31

```
sorted_members = sorted(members.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```

I can't see the '<' anywhere in that line... how can I fix it?

Comment: `members[member] = member.count` is adding the `count` method to `members`. You'd need to call `count` first, like `count(some_data)`. `<` is being used internally by `sorted`.

Comment: but count is a class attribute, im not that good so maybe i missunderstood

Comment: `member_list` appears to hold strings, not `Cal`s (`Cal.member_list.append(name)`), so `count` is a method of `str`, not an attribute of your class.

Comment: Maybe you meant to do `Cal.member_list.append(self)` in the `__init__` method to save the actual objects, and their name strings. This way when you do `member.count` you will get the attribute

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)